# Working with .pkg (Mac OS X package) files with Objective-C & Cocoa Framework

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, package

My question is:

Can I do something with 'package' (.pkg files) right from my Cocoa application's code? For example - create new one or  read / write files into existing package?

By the way, any standard command line programs also could help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an API for working with installer packages.

You could run the `installer` command-line tool using `NSTask` and parse the output. Have a look at the man page for the options it takes.

Comment: Yeah, I know about this. But using `installer` all that I can - it get a list of contents of some package (it gives me a list of folders without content of this folders).

Comment: I'm looking at 'PackageMaker' from Xcode and not understand how it works without some API for working with pkg.

Comment: @Eric There is a **private** framework called Install but, being a private framework, you won’t find any official documentation about it. Also, you won’t be able to use it in MAS-targeted applications.

Comment: @Bavarious Thank you for the answer. I'm understand that's private API, so I'm trying to search some part of non-official guides, articles, etc about it.